# condition assign to const variable

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a regex where I am checking for the condition with certain names.

```
const nameMatch = () => {
      return ( !this.state.name.match("^Jen.*") || !this.state.name.endsWith("ez") );
    }
```

In this, I get the values of `nameMatch` as `() => { return ( !this.state.name.match("^Jen.*") || this.state.name.endsWith("ez") ); }` rather than true or not

I am doing if(nameMatch) {...}

but rather I would need the ones that match.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a function to the const nameMatch.
These types of functions are called fat arrow functions.

If you wanted to get the value in the `nameMatch` variable, you can try:

```
const nameMatch = (!this.state.name.match("^Jen.*") || !this.state.name.endsWith("ez"))
```

A simpler way of expressing the logic is:

```
const nameMatch = !(this.state.name.match("^Jen.*") &&  this.state.name.endsWith("ez"))
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get null in that statement somehow. Thats the reason I changed to the above mentioned method.

Answer (score 2):

A breakdown of the regex `"^Jen.*"`:

`^` asserts the position the start of a line, where lines are delimited by `\n`.

`Jen` is a case sensitive match for the characters "Jen".

`.*` matches any character except for line terminators (`\n`) between zero and unlimited times.

Therefore as I understand your question, you're asking how to find and return every name which does not start with "Jen" or end with "ez".

If `this.state.name` is an `Array` of names, then you can return all of the names that do not start with "Jen" or end with "ez" using the following example:

```
var names = ['menez', 'asJenas', 'benez', 'destruction', 'present', 'Jenosus', 'ezJen'];

const nameMatch = names.filter((word) => { 
  return !(word.startsWith("Jen") || word.endsWith("ez"));
});

console.log(nameMatch);
// expected output: Array ["asJenas", "destruction", "present", "ezJen"]
```

If `this.state.name` is a `String` containing multiple names with new line (`\n`) delimiters in it, then you can first extract an array of names from the string and then use the above code, for example:

```
var names = "menez\nasJenas\nbenez\ndestruction\npresent\nJenosus\nezJen"

const namesArray = names.split("\n");

const nameMatch = namesArray.filter((word) => { 
  return !(word.startsWith("Jen") || word.endsWith("ez"));
});

console.log(nameMatch);
// expected output: Array ["asJenas", "destruction", "present", "ezJen"]
```

If `this.state.name` is a `String` containing a single name, then you can use the following function, which will return true if the name does not start with "Jen" or end with "ez":

```
const nameMatch = (name) => {
    return !(name.startsWith("Jen") || name.endsWith("ez"));
};
```

You can use it like so:

```
const nameMatch = (name) => {
    return !(name.startsWith("Jen") || name.endsWith("ez"));
};

var names = "Ben";

if (nameMatch(names)) {
    console.log("This name matched");
}
// expected output: "This name matched"
```

Please keep in mind that where I have used `names`, you will need to swap it to `this.state.name`.

Answer (score 0):

`nameMatch` is a function, so you need execute it to get the result, just call `nameMatch()` instead `nameMatch`